# Расположение элементов menustrip c#

Tags: c#, winforms, menu

Всем привет. В шарпе новичок. Появился такой вопрос.
Как сделать чтобы  добавляемый элемент в `ToolStrip` (появляется, например, от нажатия на кнопку) был сверху(обратное Append) и чтобы у него был свой индекс к которому в последующим можно будет обратиться.
Нашел как добавляются элементы `Menu.DropDownItems.Add("Новый элемент")` но это без индекса.

Comment: Используйте метод `Insert`.

Comment: Можете порекомендовать, где можно более подробно ознакомится со всеми методами меню?

Comment: Интеллисенс в Студии подсказывает имеющиеся свойства и методы классов, а также показывает их описание. Или смотрите [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripitemcollection?view=net-5.0) (в левом нижнем углу выберите язык)

Comment: Удалите вопрос и ответ, зарегестрируйтесь и задайте вопрос снова.